# splice can't remove the first element in javascript

Tags: javascript, angular, slice, splice

In angular2, my HTML is calling removeThisForm in javascript. The event is an object of File Array. For each object in File Array, I generate a form in angular2.

```
(click)=removeThisForm(event)
```

In javascript, I am trying to remove the file that is passing in.

```
removeThisForm(file) {
    var removableIndex = arr.indexOf(file);
    if (removeIndex >= 0) {
        arr = arr.splice(removableIndex);
    }
```

I am able to remove any form passing in, except the first one. I tried shift(), slice() and splice(0,1). When I did splice(0,1), I am getting an error of "Form submission canceled because the form is not connected".

Comment: Try `arr.splice(removableIndex,1);`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You've omitted to pass second argument to the [Array.prototype.splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) method (an integer representing the number of elements to be deleted). Try this:

```
removeThisForm(file) {
    var removableIndex = arr.indexOf(file);
    if (removeIndex >= 0) {
        arr.splice(removableIndex, 1);
    } 
}
```

Also, the `Array.prototype.splice` method returns an array containing the deleted elements. Therefore, you can't say:

```
arr = arr.splice(removableIndex, 1);
```

as it will override your `arr` with the returned value of `Array.prototype.splice` method.

Comment: Oh ha. I didn't know it return an array of deleted elements. Thanks!